# How can I set up Mutt to correctly handle Gmail folders?

Tags: gmail, mutt

Whenever I use mutt, it saves my sent messages in a Gmail folder it created called "[Imap]/Sent". Similarly, instead of going to the Trash, archived messages end up in a new folder called "[Imap]/Trash". What I'd like to do is get mutt to save my sent messages in the default Gmail folder called Sent Mail, and to have archived messages go to the default gmail folder called Trash. Is there a way to do that?

Here is what I think is the relevant part of my .muttrc:

```
set folder=imaps://imap.gmail.com
set spoolfile=imaps://imap.gmail.com/INBOX
set record=imaps://imap.gmail.com/Sent
set postponed=imaps://imap.gmail.com/Drafts
set trash=imaps://imap.gmail.com/Trash
```

Here is a screenshot of this redundancy problem:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I [Googled](https://www.google.com/search?q=imap%20gmail%20mutt) the subject, and [the first result](http://crunchbanglinux.org/wiki/howto/howto_setup_mutt_with_gmail_imap) suggests the following for setting up [remote folders](http://crunchbanglinux.org/wiki/howto/howto_setup_mutt_with_gmail_imap#remote_folders):

```
set folder = "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993"
set spoolfile = "+INBOX"
set postponed ="+[Gmail]/Drafts"
set trash = "imaps://imap.gmail.com/[Gmail]/Trash"
```

Basically, it would like you have to include `[Gmail]/` in the folder path, to access the original Gmail folders.

So, perhaps this will work:

```
set folder=imaps://imap.gmail.com
set spoolfile=imaps://imap.gmail.com/INBOX
set record="imaps://imap.gmail.com/[Gmail]/Sent Mail"
set postponed="imaps://imap.gmail.com/[Gmail]/Drafts"
set trash="imaps://imap.gmail.com/[Gmail]/Trash"
```

Note that messages in `[Gmail]/Trash` will be deleted after 30 days, so, as per http://support.google.com/mail/answer/78755?hl=en, you might want to set your trash to All Mail instead:

```
set trash="imaps://imap.gmail.com/[Gmail]/All Mail"
```